# Twisted, how can ProcessProtocol receive stdout w/o buffering?

Tags: python, twisted, multiprocessing, buffering

I'm using external process which writes short line of output for each chunk of data processed. I would like to react after each of these lines without any additional delay. However, seems that `.outReceived()` of `ProcessProtocol` is buffered. Docs state:

> .outReceived(data): This is called with data that was received from
>   the process' stdout pipe. **Pipes tend to provide data in larger
>   chunks than sockets (one kilobyte is a common buffer size)**, so you
>   may not experience the "random dribs and drabs" behavior typical of
>   network sockets, but regardless you should be prepared to deal if you
>   don't get all your data in a single call. To do it properly,
>   outReceived ought to simply accumulate the data and put off doing
>   anything with it until the process has finished.

The result is, that I get output in one chunk after whole processing is done. How can I force `ProcessProtocol` not to buffer stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using external process which writes short line of output for each chunk of data processed. I would like to react after each of these lines without any additional delay.
>
> The result is, that I get output in one chunk after whole processing is done. How can I force ProcessProtocol not to buffer stdout?

The buffering is happening in the producer process, not the consumer. Standard C library `stdout` is line-buffered only when connected to a terminal, otherwise it is fully-buffered. This is what causes the producer process to output data in large chunks rather than line by line when it is not connected to a terminal.

Use [stdbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) utility to force producer process' `stdout` to be line-buffered.

If the producer process is a python script use `-u` python interpreter switch to completely turn off buffering of the standard streams. `stdbuf` utility is better though.

Comment: Not directly an answer, but sure contains clear pointer to it. As you've said stdout is line-buffered when connected to terminal, thus using `spawnProcess` with `usePTY=True` solved this.

Comment: I am not familiar with twisted to tell whether `usePTY` is useful. Standard C library uses `isatty()` function to detect if it's connected to a terminal. Hence, another option is to `LD_PRELOAD` a library that super-imposes `isatty()` to always return `1`.

Comment: I've just checked and `usePTY` helped, I'm getting my output line by line as I've wanted. Thanx.

Comment: usePTY combines stdout with stderr, and I need them separate (one is protocol stream, the other is.. errors.) Be aware of this when you choose this solution, and consider one of the others. If python -u isn't an option, consider os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)